# xv6 add a system call that counts system calls

Tags: c, system-calls, xv6

EDIT:

GOT IT

here is what I did:

in syscall.c:

```
extern int numSysCalls;
```

in sysproc.c:

```
int numSysCalls = -1;
```

---

Okay, so I'm working on implementing an easy system call that returns the number of times a system call has been made. Seems easy, but I'm getting an error I don't understand...

Basically, here is what I did:
in syscall.c there is a function called syscall() that checks whether it is a syscall or not. I have basically declared a variable and am incrementing it every time this function is called.

Var Declaration in syscall.c:

```
18: int16_t numSysCalls = -1; //global
```

Syscall() function:

```
115:  void syscall(void){
116:     numSysCalls++; 
...
```

Error I'm getting:

```
kernel/syscall.c:116: error: ‘numSysCalls’ undeclared (first use in this function)
kernel/syscall.c:116: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
kernel/syscall.c:116: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Then, in sysproc.c, I have the same extern int and simply return the int when I call my function numCalls, as follows:

Extern Variable in sysproc.c:

```
extern int numSysCalls;
```

Method in question:

```
int sys_numSys(void){
if (numSysCalls == -1) return numSysCalls;
else return numSysCalls + 1;
}
```

In summary: numSysCalls should be incremented *whenever* a syscall (of any kind) is called - successful or not.

numSys only returns the number, or -1 if error.

Comment: is the extern visible from syscall.c?

Comment: yes. See above edit. (I accidentally clipped the "extern" when I pasted here)

Comment: the definition is type int16_t and the extern is type int.

Comment: Okay I changed the following:

**extern int numSysCalls = -1;** to **extern int16_t numSysCalls = -1;**

No cigar. Same error.

Comment: Basically, it would appear that syscall() isn't in the scope of the global variable - which it SHOULD be. I am not understanding the issue. numSysCalls is definitely in the global scope, and syscall() is not within any other function.

Comment: GOT IT
here is what I did:

in syscall.c: 
extern int numSysCalls;

in sysproc.c:
int numSysCalls = -1;

Comment: That should have been ok. Are you compiling these modules together or separately? Aha yes the types differed. That explains it!

Comment: syscall.c would have required definition `int16_t numsysCalls` but compiler did not find it - the definition in sysproc.c was type int.