# How to add a system call to get the count of a particular system call when process invokes it in XV6 OS

Tags: xv6

Can some one help me in adding a system call called getcount(system call) to XV6? which has an argument system call. when ever a system call is made by the process it should increase the count and should keep track of the count. after the completion of process it should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653195/xv6-add-a-system-call-that-counts-system-calls?rq=1).

It has been asked and answered by the same person who asked the question. It is a valid way but since this sounds like a homework question I would encourage you to try and come up with another way of doing it. I know there is one because I have done it myself.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6?rq=1) , is also another stackoverflow question and its answers that could prove useful to you.

Good Luck!